# Representing a fraction in binary?

Tags: data-structures, rational-numbers

I'm looking at binary data representations for fractions, and I was wondering what kind of a data structure the fraction would have if you were to store both the numerator and denominator that store a fraction.  Is it just two separate numbers that have no relation but are combined when used in a calculation?

Comment: That's implementation-defined. A pair of integers is perhaps the easiest representation. Note that `double` is a floating-point type, not a fractional type.

Comment: There isn't much else you can do with two numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store rational numbers without losing precision the correct way is to store both the numerator and denominator.

In practice most people use either floating-point math or built-in/library arbitrary-precision number data-types (e.g. [Java's BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)).

If you specifically want to use a data-type for fractions, [some languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_data_type#Language_support) have built-in types for rational numbers. For most other languages there is usually a library with a usable datatype (e.g. for Java Apache Commons has a [Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/Fraction.html) class and for C/C++ GMP has a [mpq_t datatype](http://gmplib.org/manual/Rational-Number-Functions.html#Rational-Number-Functions))